# How to visually join river to lake in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have two shapefiles, one is for landuse (which contains forests, and also lakes), and another one for rivers. When I set the both water types to have outlines, they are not joined nicely - they overlap, because river end has an outline too. Is there a method to join them "nicely", like you do with roads (and enabling levels)?

Example here:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbol levels work separately for each layer. As I see it, you have two options:

1. duplicate river layer to have the darker outline under the lakes and the lighter line over the lakes layer
2. buffer the rivers and add the buffers to the lake layer

Comment: Lakes are part of a uniform layer of all landuse, if I put anything under it, it will not be visible at all. What do you mean by buffer?

Comment: You could extract the lakes from the landuse layer first. Here's a video on the buffer function: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tmk16FloieQ

Comment: Thanks, I ended up removing outlines from the lakes and rivers, as any other option was complicated (I have nearly the whole country, and each "tile" consists of 7-9 SHP files. I would have gone mad if I would have to combine layers or extract anything from them).